# Compress xlog when restoring postgres db?

Tags: postgresql-9.1, wal

For postgres,

I used 'pg_dump' to dump a db, then use 'psql' to restore the db at the other sever. I found there are huge volume of WAL logs created at pg_xlog/ which consumed a lot of disk space.

Is there any way postgres provides to compress these WAL logs automatically?

I saw a 'archive_command' setup in postgres' manual. Is it the correct direction?

Yang

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `archive_command` is the directive you're looking for. From [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-ARCHIVE-COMMAND):

> `archive_command (string)`
>
> The shell command to execute to archive a completed WAL file segment.
>   Any %p in the string is replaced by the path name of the file to
>   archive, and any %f is replaced by only the file name. (The path name
>   is relative to the working directory of the server, i.e., the
>   cluster's data directory.) Use %% to embed an actual % character in
>   the command. It is important for the command to return a zero exit
>   status only if it succeeds. For more information see Section 24.3.1.
>
> This parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or on the
>   server command line. It is ignored unless archive_mode was enabled at
>   server start. If archive_command is an empty string (the default)
>   while archive_mode is enabled, WAL archiving is temporarily disabled,
>   but the server continues to accumulate WAL segment files in the
>   expectation that a command will soon be provided. Setting
>   archive_command to a command that does nothing but return true, e.g.
>   /bin/true (REM on Windows), effectively disables archiving, but also
>   breaks the chain of WAL files needed for archive recovery, so it
>   should only be used in unusual circumstances.

The [Postgres wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication#How_to_Use) has one example:

```
# Enable WAL archiving on the primary to an archive directory accessible from
# the standby. If wal_keep_segments is a high enough number to retain the WAL
# segments required for the standby server, this is not necessary.
archive_mode    = on
archive_command = 'cp %p /path_to/archive/%f'
```